# WPF and Workflow foundation don't work together

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, workflow-foundation

I have really strange problem. I've created WPF project in 2012 or 2013 VS it doesn't matter. I use .NET 4.5.

1. I add a new Activity (Workflow class) to that project. Its name is CustomActivity.
2. Then I add a new class that has got an attached property, example below:

   ```
   public class AttachedObject : DependencyObject
   {
   public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                 "Name",
                 typeof(string),
                 typeof(AttachedObject),
                 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
   string.Empty,frameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

   public static void SetName(ContentControl element, string value)
   {
       element.SetValue(NameProperty, value);
   }

   public static string GetName(ContentControl element)
   {
       return (string)element.GetValue(NameProperty);
   }
   }
   ```
3. The last step is to change MainWindow class that way:

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       var activity = new CustomActivity();
   }
   ```

   ```
   <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1;assembly=WpfApplication1"
           Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
       <Grid>
           <ContentControl wpfApplication1:AttachedObject.Name="MainArea"/>
       </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```

The problem is it doesn't compile because of below error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'CustomActivity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs  13  32  WpfApplication1

CustomActivity has a default namespace. In obj folder there is CustomActivity.g.cs generated, so I have no idea what's going on.
It's 100% reproducible. When I remove using of CustomActivity or using of AttachedObject from xaml then the problem disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1;assembly=WpfApplication1"
```

with this

```
 xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

The error you're seeing is due to a "known" issue in WPF applications that xaml namespaces that reference clr namespace from current assembly your in don't require the full assembly qualified name. If you were to declare a xaml namespace that references a clr namespace from another assembly, than you would have to specify the full name (with the ;[assemblyname] syntax).

Workflow Foundation has nothing to do with it.

EDIT:
Didn't realize it was a xaml activity.
But still, you can make it work, maybe, with a few hacks, but I wouldn't recommend it.
The reason you get that error is due to the different code generation and build action VS uses when creating xaml artifacts for WPF (Page):

```
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);
```

and when creating xaml activities (XamlAppDef):

```
 typeof(CustomActivity).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
```

If you turn your CustomActivity xaml build action to Page, the whole thing will compile - but i'm guessing something else might be broken someplace else...or not, who knows. My guess is that these two kinds of xaml were not meant to live together in a VS WPF application project template. But you can still define activities in a WF activity library, that way your activities will also be more easily reusable for other projects, WPF, console or even services.

Comment: It doesn't work. there is an error: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'CustomActivity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs 13 32 WpfApplication1

Comment: Can you post your full code? including the CustomActivity and possibly also your csproj?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue under Visual Studio 2017.

The problem in my case is that Visual Studio is not compiling the Workflow activities before the code that use them.

To fix it, what I did is to move all workflows to other project dll, so visual Studio is forced to compile the workflows before the classes that make use of them.